# Jquery Scroll Not Appearing Across All Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I may be overlooking something dumb... but I'm using this code and normally, would expect it to run across all pages as it's injected to the /head of the document. For some reason, it's only applying to the home page and no other page.... Can't seem to see what's wrong with it. Am I missing chars somewhere or...  Any idea what's wrong that it only applies to one page?

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var sT = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (sT >= 600) {
            $('#header, #siteTitle a, #mainNavigation .external > a').addClass('colNav')
        } else {
            $('#header, #siteTitle a, #mainNavigation .external > a').removeClass('colNav')
        }
    })
})
```

**CSS**

```
.colNav {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A.) Check that the script is loading properly on the pages, other than your front page. If you use Firefox getting Firebug is a great way to gain some info on what's happening behind the scenes.

B.) Do the following exist on the other pages:

- a container with the ID - #header,
- an anchor in a container with the the ID - #siteTitle a
- an anchor in a container with the ID #mainNavigation .external > a

C.) You have some semicolons missing after the last two closing ")" - but assuming this works on your front page this is probably not going to be an issue.. should fix this though.

Comment: I fixed the two missing semi-colons, you're right. Thank you. 

Yes, all ID/Class exist but, working in a CMS that has ten hundred other classes involved  --- I targeted global selectors yet in rechecking since you called it out (the obvious too) --- come to find, there's other classes added --- so this answers the question why the targets aren't explicitly working globally. Looking at it for so long it was becoming a blur.... Thx!